# Change privacy policy text shown at the time of registration in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

How to change woocommerce privacy policy? I mean the text shown at the time of registration:

> "Your personal data will be used to process your order, support your
>   experience throughout this website, and for other purposes described
>   in our privacy policy."

what if I want to remove it? Is it possible as I have already added a privacy policy checkbox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide us example code you have tried already so far?

Comment: I have added some extra fields using child theme and "wc_get_template( 'checkout/terms.php' );" to add the privacy policy checkbox but its showing two times. tried to edit "class-wc-settings-accounts.php" that also didn't work. My registration form link https://otpeople.com/my-account/

Comment: @NaveenBisht You don't need to add extra fields, you just need to update settings

Answer (score 9):

If you look at Woocommerce settings under **"Accounts & Privacy"** tab in **"Privacy policy"** section, you will see that you have some dedicated fields where you can make changes easily:

[image]
[image]